# how to use function under the if statement in python?

Tags: python, console

trying to implement play again feature in a tic tac toe in python

the function under the if statement doesn't work how can I solve this?

after play_againg print and take the input, it doesn't re-execute the play_game() function 
so why is that?

```
def play_again():
    print ("do you want to play again ?")
    print ("1 - yes / 2 - no")
    opinion = int(input()) 
    if opinion == 1:
         winner = None #updating the varible which moves the game to default 
         game_still_going = True
         current_player = "X"
         play_game()
    else :
        print("thanks for playing") 

play_game()
play_again()
```

Comment: if `opinion == 1`, then `play_game()` will run. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Can you add more information about the code.. and the part after `def play_again():` should be indented block.

Comment: Note that this only allows you to replay once. If you want to allow unlimited replays, you should use a loop.

Comment: @cercigenicate  still it doesn't work

Comment: Does it print `thanks for playing`?

Comment: @Barmar  yes it does

Comment: it can even accept the first option but it doesn't execute the play game function again

Comment: I tried your code and it played the game a second time when I entered 1.

Comment: `game_still_going` and `current_player` in `play_again` are local variable and they will not change value of global variables - and if you use global `game_still_going` in `play_game()` then it may have still old value and it will not run again.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to check values in variables - ie. `print(option, type(option), option == 1)`